# Find missing Spark partition

Tags: java, apache-spark

If we are reading a multi-partition parquet & let's say if any partition is missing from that, is there a way to find out that using Spark configuration to make sure that it has all the records intended for?

Comment: I don't think the question makes any sense. Sorry.

Comment: Did you mean to ask about https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery ?